# Error: dot: can't open 'small_tree.dot'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```
# используем .dot формат для визуализации дерева
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
export_graphviz(clf_tree, feature_names=['x1', 'x2'], 
out_file='small_tree.dot', filled=True)
# для этого понадобится библиотека pydot (pip install pydot)
!dot -Tpng 'small_tree.dot' -o 'small_tree.png'
```

Error: dot: can't open 'small_tree.dot'

Comment: код на питоне пишет 'small_tree.dot'; если бы его запускали, смотрите, где он; и там же запускайте dot